# How to capture data from form and put these data into a HTML file

Tags: php

My company want to make things easier. We always create a letter for our customers to say our thank you. We have a letter that has the same content. As an example:

> hi (customer_name),
>
> thank you for doing business with us! we will contact u at (customer
>   number)

What I want to do is to let my staff edit the content of the letter from a form like:

Customer name: _________________
phone: _________________
[submit button]

On click of the submit button, the data from here will be saved into a DB and append to the letter just now and the letter will also saved into a DB.

Comment: or maybe u guys can help me with what term to search? because i dont know what to search for this kind of thing

Comment: Have you tried anythings? post your code here so we can have a look where things are going wrong?

Comment: i dont have anything. but have the idea of somehow like this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp BUT what i want is after this process i want to save .pdf or .html file into db so my staff can refer to it in future

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that hard. Firstly, you need to create a form.

```
<form method="post" action="path/to/file.php">
   <input type="text" name="customerName" placeholder="Customer Name">
   <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
   <input type="submit" value="Generate">
</form>
```

So, now when the button is clicked, the data will be sent through a POST request to the URL specified in the `action` attribute defined in the `<form>` tag. So, to fetch a value from what was entered in the form, you have to access the [`$_POST` super global](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). Every single form that is submitted with the `method` attribute set to `post`, all the input fields data is moved on to the `$_POST` super global, and to access a specific value for a specific input field, you will have to fetch it from the index in the `$_POST` super global which is equal to the value specified in the input field `name` attribute. So, for example, to get the customer name, you would try to get it from `$_POST['customerName'`.

So, you can do something like this:

```
$string = "hi " . $_POST['customerName'] . ",<br /><br />thank you for doing business with us! we will contact u at " . $_POST['phoneNumber'];
```

And now, you can save this `$string` to your database in a table.

More information on this topic can be found here:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php
- http://myphpform.com/
- http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/form-handler/

Comment: yup that is correct. Thanks. :) however my problem is after we got all of this value i want to save it into a db as a file of .pdf or .html i mean for customer A the letter will be different for customer B the letter will be different so i want to save each one of the letter copy in a db so that later my staff can open it back

Comment: @XdesignWeb Check my update. Also, feel free to tick this if this satisfies you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

         $letter = 'hi (customer_name),

thank you for doing business with us! we will contact u at (customer_number)';


          $letter = str_replace('(customer_name)', $_POST['customer_name'], $letter);


          $letter .= str_replace('(customer_number)', $_POST['customer_number'], $letter);

           //db save code here..
            //save $letter variable into db

     }
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="customer_name" /><br />
<input type="text" name="customer_number" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```